# Line chart with ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to create JavaFX line chart with 2 lines.

I tested this code:

```
    import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    private static final int MAX_DATA_POINTS = 50;

    private Series series;
    private Series series2;
    private int xSeriesData = 0;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number>();
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ2 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number>();
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private AddToQueue addToQueue;
    private NumberAxis xAxis;

    private void init(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, MAX_DATA_POINTS, MAX_DATA_POINTS / 10);
        xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);

        //-- Chart
        final AreaChart<Number, Number> sc = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis)
        {
            // Override to remove symbols on each data point
            @Override
            protected void dataItemAdded(Series<Number, Number> series, int itemIndex, Data<Number, Number> item)
            {
            }
        };
        sc.setAnimated(false);
        sc.setId("liveAreaChart");
        sc.setTitle("Animated Area Chart");

        //-- Chart Series
        series = new AreaChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series.setName("Area Chart Series");
        series2 = new AreaChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series2.setName("Area Chart Series");
        sc.getData().addAll(series, series2);

        xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
        xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(sc));
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();

        //-- Prepare Executor Services
        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory()
        {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                return thread;
            }
        });
        addToQueue = new AddToQueue();
        executor.execute(addToQueue);
        //-- Prepare Timeline
        prepareTimeline();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class AddToQueue implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                // add a item of random data to queue
                dataQ.add(Math.random());
                dataQ2.add(Math.random());
                Thread.sleep(200);
                executor.execute(this);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    //-- Timeline gets called in the JavaFX Main thread
    private void prepareTimeline()
    {
        // Every frame to take any data from queue and add to chart
        new AnimationTimer()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now)
            {
                addDataToSeries();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void addDataToSeries()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        { //-- add 20 numbers to the plot+
            if (dataQ.isEmpty())
                break;
            series.getData().add(new AreaChart.Data(xSeriesData++, dataQ.remove()));

            if (dataQ2.isEmpty())
                break;
            series2.getData().add(new AreaChart.Data(xSeriesData, dataQ2.remove()));
        }
        // remove points to keep us at no more than MAX_DATA_POINTS
        if (series.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS)
        {
            series.getData().remove(0, series.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        }

        // remove points to keep us at no more than MAX_DATA_POINTS
        if (series2.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS)
        {
            series2.getData().remove(0, series2.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        }

        // update
        xAxis.setLowerBound(xSeriesData - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(xSeriesData - 1);
    }
}
```

For some reason new data is added but old is always displayed. I want to delete the old line history and display the line chart as animation. Can you give some advice?

**EDIT**

I noticed this space between the lines.

[image]

Comment: This works pretty much as expected for me: once there are 50 points in each of the series, earlier points are removed. Note you're incrementing the `x` value on each addition *on each series*, so you don't get to 50 points until `x = 150`. You have created two charts, one of which (`sc`) isn't displayed at all, and you are using the same `xAxis` for both charts, which I think is messing up the axis sizing; if you clean that up I think this works fine.

Comment: Actually, looking at the code a little more closely, you don't use the same `xAxis` for both charts; but you only configure and change the range on the one that is associated with the unused chart `sc`, not the one used by the chart you display, `lineChart`. If you remove the unused chart and clean up the use of the axes, etc, it will all work fine.

Comment: Can you help to fix this code?

Comment: Just take out the extra LineChart and go from there.

Comment: I managed to create the desired result. Is this code correct or I can remove some of the code?

Comment: That looks right to me...

Comment: By the way I noticed this space between the lines. Is this a code issue? I'm missing something?

Comment: The space is there because you increment xSeriesData in the addDataToSeries twice, i. e. in different loops. Could you post your full code when you're done please, I'm interested in this solution as well.

Comment: @Roland I updated the code as you proposed but still I see the empty space as the picture.

Comment: You're still doing the xSeriesData++ twice. Just do it only once in the loop.

Comment: @Roland Can you please show me quick example of your idea in http://pastebin.com/? When I remove the second xSeriesData++  there is no second line. I don't get your idea.

Comment: Can't access pastebin.com here. However, just put xSeriesData++; at the end of the for-loop and only use new AreaChart.Data(xSeriesData...); without the ++.

Comment: I updated the answer. Now the space is gone. By the way is there any option for code optimization? I have a problem with the performance when I use 8+ charts on my PC. CPU is very height.